# How to match a word in Python and if not exists how to raise Exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to match a word "None" and if not found I need to raise exception. I have tried with below python code.

```
    import re

    text = "None"

    match1 = re.match('.*None', text)
    mat1 = ['None']

    if match1 == mat1:
        print "match found"
    if match1 != mat1:
        raise Exception('Not found...')
```

But Always I am getting the below error:

```
    C:\Users\test\Desktop>python test.py
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
          raise Exception('Not found...')
    Exception: Not found...

    C:\Users\test\Desktop>
```

Can anyone please guide to me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you absolutely need to use regex?

This seems easier:

```
if "None" not in text:
    raise Exception('Not found...')
```

This of course only matches a literal "None" and not e.g. "none". But that is the case of your regex as well...

Comment: @mirisval Thanks for your answer. Its working. But with exception, its also throws this errors "C:\Users\test\Desktop>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    raise Exception('Not found...')
Exception: Not found...

C:\Users\test\Desktop>"

Comment: What is in `text` when the error exception is thrown? That is the exception that you wanted to raise, so maybe it is the correct behavior.

Comment: @mirisval I mean the following error "Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 21, in <module>". Is there a way to fix this error not to appear

Comment: Well of course, you have raised the error, you need to catch it, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html. If you let it bubble up and don't catch it, this is what happens.

Answer (score 3):

When using regular expressions, the result of a `match` method is a match object with which you perform other methods. You may even compare it directly in an `if-else` conditional to check whether any matching was performed.

If you really want to use RE, the proper way of doing so is:

```
if match1:
    print 'Match found'
else:
    raise Exception('Not found...')
```

A probably easier way of checking whether `None` exists in a sentence is using the `in` operator:

```
if 'None' in text:
    print 'Found None'
else:
    raise Exception('None not found')
```

The [Python documentation on regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#examples) provide simple examples that helps you in understanding how to use this module.

Answer (score 2):

`re.match` returns a match object not a list.

```
import re

text = "None"

match1 = re.match('.*None', text)

if not match1:
    raise Exception('Not found...')
print(match1.group(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way `re.match` return value is assumed

`re.match('.*None', text)`

**from Documentation**

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance. Return `None` if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

therefore `if match1 == mat1:` is always false because `mat1 = ['None']` hence you are getting your exception always.